# How to express an indefinitely nestled fraction recursively in python

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python and am trying to improve my understanding of recursion by approximating various mathematical constants. I found an expression for e (2.718...) in the form of an infinitely nestled fraction: 2 + 2/(2 + 3/(3 + 4/(4 + 5/ ...

Please see the image: at the following address:

https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/98e36faf34d05cb60882518818c7e6c9c7dca5e4

I would like to find a way to approximate this value recursively, but I am lost as to where to start when it comes to writing the return line for the function. The particular barrier is that the numbers get larger as you go down the layers of the fraction so an f(n - 1) cannot be used in the return line with a base case of n == 0. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any recursive function will need a stop condition so that it can eventually produce a result (i.e. not loop indefinitely).

Here is an example with the number of iterations as the stopping condition (you could use precision, time, or any other scheme to make the recursion stop):

```
def neperian(n,d=1):
    if d == n : return n
    return max(2,d) + (d+1)/neperian(n,d+1)

print(neperian(10)) # 2.7182818427778273
print(neperian(20)) # 2.7182818284590455
```

This one converges very rapidly so you will hit the maximum floating point precision long before you run into large number issues.

Comment: Thanks! This is more or less what I ended up figuring out on my own after some more playing around.

Answer (score 1):

That's a continued fraction. Note well that the continued fraction of an irrational number has an infinite number of digits in its expansion.  The common way is to write a generator that yields the digits of the continued fraction.

See gosper continued fraction. There is also at least one Python module for continued fractions

Answer (score 0):

In the end I came up with this:

```
n = 10
def f(x):
    if x == n:
        return 1
    else:
        return x/(x + f(x + 1))

e = 2 + f(2)
```

I'm not sure if this is the most concise way of conveying this particular expansion of e in code. Any suggestions to refine it would be much appreciated!